# OpenLayers 2.13 eating left mouse click?

Tags: javascript, click, openlayers

I have some custom context menus shown on the map that listen for document "click" events so they can be hidden when the user left clicks outside the menu.  They work fine in OpenLayers 2.12 but are now broken with 2.13.   It seems the OpenLayers.Map is not propagating left mouse clicks, is this intended?  Suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, I found the cause/solution.  There is a new map property "fallThrough" that defaults to false (eat the events).